# CLR WebBrowser and C# InternetExplorer fail to login

Tags: c#, .net

My programm can not login to the marathonbet.com. I made two attempts - CLR project with WebBrowser control and C# with

```
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        object Empty = 0;
        object URL = "http://www.marathonbet.com";
        IE.Visible = true;
        IE.Navigate2(ref URL, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty);
```

I can not login, even if I enter login information manually. It seems to work with login to other sites (gmx.de, gmail.com, after I have adjusted FEATURE_BEHAVIORS in registry), but not with marathonbet.com - it redirects me to the additional login site with capture. InternetExplorer looks like a normal IE aplpication (IE11 is installed), but marathonbet recognizes somehow that it is created and started in C#. I have checked IE options of the manually started IE (which works properly) and InternetExplorer Object - they are the same. What can be the reason of this behaviour? Is there another way, maybe to take control over the normally started browser, and access its DOM to read and to fill the fields?

Answer (score 0):

The website is probably looking at the User Agent when the request is received, to filter out bots. You will need to modify it so that it does not look like some automated bot trying to gain access.

For more info, take a look at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. I got the user-agent header displayed, with WebBrowser it is "document.documentMode: '11'
'User-agent header: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MASBJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko'", and with the normal IE "document.documentMode: '11'
'User-agent header: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; MASBJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko'". It seems to be not a very big difference. Hm, I think I've underestimated the effort. It'll take days, not hours...